# Require user ineraction during onStop

Tags: android

**My goal:** To force user interaction during `onStop`.

**Example:** Start an `intent` and have an `Activity` launch when the user presses the `home` button or `onStop` is called.

I know this is not good practice, but we need to force user interaction if the user tries to leave the app with the `home` button.

If you have any other ideas on how to achieve this goal, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this reliably (since it's malware-like behaviour). The user will always be able to kill your app from the recent apps menu.

You can make your app be a launcher, if that's something your users would put up with and then it will get launched every time they hit home but there's no way to prevent someone from leaving your app (reliably). Plenty of hacks are possible, including a `Service`s launching `am start` (may or may not require root) but, again, totally circumventable.

If your users trust you enough (and by the sound of it, they don't have a choice), you can request the `SYSTEM_ALERT_DIALOG` permission. This allows you to position windows on top of other applications. So, the pieces of the puzzles become the following -

1. A Service tracking whether the user is in the app
2. Activities that notify the service when their `onStart`/`onStop` methods get called. When an `onStop` is called, you start a timer (by e.g. using `postDelayed` on a Handler) and cancel it when an `onStart` is called.
3. If the timer fires, it means you got an `onStop` without staying in your app. Then, you can display a window with the appropriate flags (this part is a bit low-level, since you have to talk to the `WindowManager` directly. The source code for `Dialog` is a good example here) and that gets presented on top of whatever app the user is currently viewing.

Alternatively, depending on the importance of the dialog, consider showing it as a notification that, once pressed, launches an activity with the dialog. Of course, you then run the risk of the user dismissing the notification (though you can make it ongoing to avoid that).

Comment: Killing the app is not an issue. That is ok, just need to prevent them from leaving when `home` is pressed. They can leave, just need to interact with a `dialog/activity` first. And this is enterprise level software, not intended for the general public.

Comment: Well, since it's enterprise software, I say ask for the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission and display an alert dialog when they leave the app (you can easily do this with a service that activities register with in onStart and deregister in onStop - you'll need a bit of timeout there as well). This is by far the cleanest solution and you're not fighting Android too much.

Comment: That sounds promising, can you elaborate a little further? More details on the service and such? Thanks

Comment: That is grotesque. =( I will let you know if we use this and it was successful. I am still open to other ideas though.

Comment: Anything you do to implement this will be hacky to some extent or another. Using alert windows is, in my opinion, the cleanest solution.